# Squid problems with iptables

Tags: iptables, squid

I've installed and configured Squid on Fedora Server 21 with full updates. My proxy's IP is 145.130.33.133 with port 3128. First I modified my squid.conf with my rules and everything. On my laptop with Fedora Workstation 21 works normally, meanwhile on my server it doesn't. Both, pc and laptop I've not configured iptables. What am I missing?
I'm attaching the iptables config

[image]

PD: Httpd(Apache) doesn't work when iptables service is ON

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is the current state of your firewall?

Comment: When the iptables if OFF, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule for squid appears to have an issue.  There is a space following the comma after ESTABLISHED, which could cause iptables to stop processing the subsequent rules

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED, RELATED -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
                                          ^
                                        Remove this space
```

Also, there is a rule already accepting established and related states:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I would suggest modifying the rule for the squid port be to this:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you !! many many thanks, now it works like a charm :)